# MEAN stack: Cannot load localhost page after latest git pull "Get / - - ms - -"

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I am working on a project with a fellow programmer and we have ran into a bit of show stopper. We are both new to using the MEAN stack and are having some trouble debugging an issue. My co-worker made some changes to the files and I am now unable to access our localhost page. The odd thing is instead of an error the page just doesn't load and the below messages are shown in the terminal.

```
http://localhost:3000/
We are connected
GET / - - ms - -
GET / - - ms - -
GET / - - ms - -
GET / - - ms - -
```

I have tried googling the message but it hasn't helped me narrow the problem down. I have a feeling since everything is working on his end still that maybe we forgot to add a --save to an npm install of some sort. Does anyone know if there is a way of finding discrepancies between installed dependancies that where not saved to package.json? Or if anyone knows of another reason this might be happening please let me know!

Thanks!

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var session = require('client-sessions');


// var users = require('./routes/users');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();


//set mongo db connection
var db = mongoose.connection;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("We are connected");
  };
}); 

// Bootstrap models
var models_path = __dirname + '/models'
fs.readdirSync(models_path).forEach(function (file) {
  if (file.substr(-3) == '.js') {
    require(models_path+'/'+file);
  }
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'session',
    secret: 'something',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
}));


// Attach Routes: 'index.js'
require('./routes/index')(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Buddha Bar' })
});


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//make sesssions available to the router?
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session && req.session.user) {
    User.findOne({ username: req.session.user.username }, function(err, user) {
      if (user) {
        req.user = currentUser;
        delete req.user.password; // delete the password from the session
        req.session.user = currentUser;  //refresh the session value
        res.locals.user = currentUser;
      }
      // finishing processing the middleware and run the route
      next();
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  req.db = db;
  next();
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you post the changes that were made? Or at least the current state of your main server config file or whatever sets up your express middleware - and particularly the logger... is that `morgan`?.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying! Im not sure the best way to show you changes as I cannot add a photo but it is using morgan. I will also post my app.js if you care to take a look.

Comment: when a page just doesn't load in express it's usually that a middleware isn't response/throwing/nexting, just holding on to the connection.  If it was a missing module an error would be thrown.  I see plenty of sloppy code in app.js, though nothing that explains it, it could be in routes/index as well.

Comment: some notes: http://jsbin.com/tajukecavu/2/edit?js it could also be an issue with the ordering of the middleware

Comment: Thanks a lot @generalhenry I will try fixing the code according to your comments. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments I'd first look to stripping out your middleware until you have a minimal working server and then re-adding then systematically.

Your logger does output *something* which makes me think there isn't a hanging middleware (i.e. no `next()` or other terminating call) but that maybe the request object itself, or at least some expected properties, are being tampered with. Looking at the morgan code it does look like [the dash (`-`) is its fallback token](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/master/index.js#L160) for when it can't get a value. In your case it looks like morgan can't calculate any of the values in the dev pattern other than the method and URL.